# When are step methods of mason agents executed?

Tags: java, schedule, agent, mason

I'm working on an implemantation of an ant colony algorithm. I'm supposed to model the ants as a multi agent system using mason. I think I have all the pieces in place to make it work, but im having problems with the scheduling. Right now all ants are added to the schedule, then everything else is executed and then the schedule ist processed.
How do I let 10 ants do their job, then update an array, then the 10 ants again (and so on)?

I tried some busy-waiting (shame on me) after adding the ants to the schedule:

```java
while(!schedule.scheduleComplete()){ }
```

but that didn't work as inteded, I assume because the schedule is only executed after the SimulationState.start() method has finished.

This is what my SimulationState class looks like right now. If info about any other classes is needed I'll share that as well.

```java
public class SimulationState extends SimState {

    public SimulationState(long seed) {
        super(seed);
    }

    AntColonyOptimization antColonyOptimization = new AntColonyOptimization();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doLoop(SimulationState.class, args);
        System.exit(0);
    }


    @Override
    public void start() {
        super.start();
        List<Ant> Ants = new ArrayList<>();
schedule.
        for (int c = 0; c < 2 ;c++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                Ants.add(new Ant(antColonyOptimization.pheromones));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                schedule.scheduleOnce(Ants.get(i));
            }

            antColonyOptimization.decayPheromones();
        }

        System.out.println(schedule.scheduleComplete());
    }

    @Override
    public void finish() {
        super.finish();
        System.out.println("simulation finished");
    }

}
```

Maybe I should add at least the ant's step method:

```java
@Override
    public void step(SimState state) {
        SimulationState simulationState = (SimulationState) state;
        findRoute();
        route.printRoute(takenRoute);
        calculateDistance();
//        if (antColonyOptimization.antsCounter == 9) {
//            addPheromones();
//            antColonyOptimization.decayPheromones();
//        }
        addPheromones();
        System.out.println("Ant is done!");
    }
```

I expected ten ants to be added and executed, then for the decayPheromones() method to be called and then the same procedure again.

Instead there are 10 ants added,then overwritten by 10 new ants, the decayPheromones method is executed two times before the ants are executed.